# Spring how to add resource handlers for static files from other origin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement handling requests for static resourses in Spring + Angular project. Angular app is running on `http://localhost:4200` when Spring app is running on `http://localhost:8080`.

So when I need to get an image, angular sends a request which looks like this `http://localhost:4200/screenShots/image-name.jpg`. To handle these kind of requests I've created `WebConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        String path = "file:///" + *path to folder with images on my PC*
        registry.addResourceHandler("/screenShots/**")
                .addResourceLocations(path);
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work, I get *404 (Not Found)* error. I've experimented with addind and removing `@EnableWebMvc` and `@CrossOrigin` annotations, tried to add `addCorsMappings()` method in my class like that, nothing helped.

```
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/screenShots/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
```

However when I put `http://localhost:8080/screenShots/image-name.jpg` **(changed :4200 to :8080)** string in Google address bar, it returns me my image as intended, so I wonder is there a way to add some kind of `@CrossOrigin` annotation alternative for resourse handlers cuz I haven't found any solution in the Internet yet. Thanks!

Github repo for those, who are curious (**only gameImagesRelease branch contains current piece of code**): https://github.com/Vladyslav-Bahlai/OktenGames/tree/gameImagesRelease

Answer (score 0):

For example, I will show my `MVC`-configs. I had the same problem. `Spring` did not see `HTML` files. I draw your attention to the *templates* folder.

```java
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /**
     * Making our pages visible
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/coffees").setViewName("coffees");
        registry.addViewController("/teas").setViewName("teas");
        registry.addViewController("/contacts").setViewName("contacts");
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/about").setViewName("about");
        registry.addViewController("/registration").setViewName("registration");
        registry.addViewController("/card").setViewName("card");
    }


    /**
     * This method helps Spring discover file paths
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/");
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for a quick answer, but could you describe at least in a few words why am I getting 404 error and how your code exactly solves my problem, cuz I don't understand what is `addViewControllers()` method for in my case and what you have added in `addResourceHandlers()` to help me? Would be really greatful!

Comment: Sorry, your text above code hasn't rendered when I wrote this comment

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: not really, I still don't know how to modify my class cuz it's kinda different story when working with html templates. I may try to store my images in `resources/static` folder but I doubt it will help. I think the problem is that my requests are sent from `localhost:4200` instead of `8080` and therefore are just ignored by resource handler

Comment: add in question your project structure

Comment: added link to github repo with project in the end of the question

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, I've already solved my problem. It was hiding inside my Angular project and has nothing to do with Spring project structure.